# Why does mv refuse to work?

Tags: 14.04, btrfs, mv

I am writing a small software in Java to act as a G.U.I for btrfs commands as a high school diploma project . I want to be able to take a snapshot and restore it in real time if I do a `btrfs subvolume snapshot /home /home/snapshot` and then `mv /home/snapshot /home` it works, it does a live "rollback" in Fedora, but in Ubuntu it will just say that it can't move to the same place.Why is that?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should change the location of the `/home/snapshot`. Your shell (or mv) is trying to do this:

```
mv /home/snapshot /home/snapshot
```

You can read about second form of the `mv` syntax:

```
mv [OPTION]... SOURCE... DIRECTORY
```

by typing `man mv`